# Ajax toolkit validations are server side or client side?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have one simple question (doubt).
Ajax is a server side technology so it hits the server asynchronously but when we use ajax toolkit's text-box validations then even if internet is disconnected , text-box gets validated how?? is it client side?

Comment: Both, it validates on client AND server

Answer (score 0):

Actually, AjaxToolkit generates javascript codes in pages. all validations are done in Client side.

Answer (score 0):

The `AJAXToolkit` is basically a helper that implements some client-side functionality for you. The user story in `WebForms` is all about rapid application development. The entire `WebForms` infrastructure is in place in order to wrap server-side + client-side functionality in a way that allows you to create web applications like you would `WinForms` applications. `WebForms` was developed by Microsoft to allow `WinForms` developers to use the same techniques when developing for the web.

That being said, all `asp.net` validators are **both** client-side and server-side. Doing client-side validation without server-side validation is pointless. Client-side validation (AJAX or not) is only used to give users a more responsive UI and maybe save some server round-trips for input that can be easily detected as invalid. The true validation is done server-side when the form is `POST`ed. If there were only client-side validation in place, a user with malicious intent could just circumvent the validation by posting the form from a tool like `Fiddler`. Also, what about clients which do not support `JavaScript` at all? (Rare as they might be these days...)